# Ubuntu 16.04 installer hangs on softlockup 812LC

Tags: server, system-installation, powerpc

Posting on behalf of community member  Erik Kooistra (erikk):

I am currently installing ubuntu 16.04 using net install on multiple 812LC machines. But every time the installer hangs with.

```
[  125.900503] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#4 stuck for 23s! [swapper/4:0]
```

And the installer is frozen for some time, after that sometimes i can continue the installer.

Also i can only connect to the installer using SOL the remote control does not work.

Is there a fix for this?

- [`dmesg` output](http://pastebin.com/e3e9cbMN)

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a race condition in the AST framebuffer driver that we've (now repeatedly) squashed over $time.

You should be able to add "ast.blacklist=yes" to the kernel command line to blacklist the AST framebuffer driver. This will disable the VGA port and you'll have to use the text installer (but you're already doing that).

I thought newer kernels would have had this fix in them, but perhaps this particular Ubuntu one only has one of the two/three fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `dmesg` output, there's nothing that seems to point directly to the problem cause, but it does look like either kernel or a device driver.

First, you could try a more recent kernel -- either the 16.04.1 ISO or netboot installation (both are currently at kernel 4.4.0-31.50) or the 16.04 ISO daily build [1] (currently at 4.4.0-46.67).

Second, but more of a guess, if you look at the `dmesg` log timestamps, the last message about 22 seconds before the first `CPU#x stuck for 22s` is from the `ast` (video) driver [65.9 - 39.1 = 26.8 seconds]. So, you can try to blacklist the `ast` module with the kernel parameter `modprobe.blacklist=ast`.

Hope this helps.

[1] http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/xenial/daily/current/